# Floating a UILabel above OpenFlow

Tags: iphone, coverflow

How do you get a UILabel to float above Alex Fajkowski's implementation of CoverFlow called OpenFlow?

Ok I've figured it out. I just had to use bringSubviewToFront with the UILabel.

Thanks to everybody who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `OpenFlow` instance and a `UILabel` instance subviews of a parent `view`, placing the label atop with flow view using `-insertSubview:atIndex:`, `-addSubview:` or similar e.g.:

```
[self.view addSubview:myOpenFlow];
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: How do I do this with a UILabel that is in a Nib? The UIViewController Nib's view is a AFOpenFlowView, and I'd like to lay out my interface elements in it rather then do so programmatically. Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this in IB, I think it's even simpler: Make your view controller `view` a `UIView` view, drag an `AFOpenFlowView` view "under" or "into" the top-most `UIView` and drag a `UILabel` under or into the `UIView`. In your view controller, set these as properties as `IBOutlet` types and wire them up in IB as per usual. This accomplishes the same ordering of subviews as the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, try this: edit the AFOpenFlowView in IB and add the label view as a subview of that wherever you want it to appear, then set the attributes on the view to Hidden if you don't want it to appear by default. Create an IBOutlet for the label view in your controller so you can easily manipulate it, such as setting hidden to show in order to show it. I'm not familiar with open flow so I'm not sure if it will programmatically create a subview that will obscure your label. If so you may need to use the outlet to move it to the front using UIView methods.

Answer (score 0):

The Openflow example code shows a **perfect** demonstration of this. Alex adds an info button in the top right of the openflow view using interface builder. This is **exactly** what you are asking for.

I would add that if you can't understand what is going on from the example code, you should look at more code examples from Apple demonstrating simple UIView usage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so easy because the label name has to change for each picture. We have to work with index, and with event.. move.. tap.. selected...I'm working on too !